# Data.ConfigFile not using the Bool instance of get

Tags: haskell, type-inference

According to https://hackage.haskell.org/package/ConfigFile-1.0.5/docs/Data-ConfigFile.html, the package will convert a value in a config. file to a Bool.  The following code:

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}


import qualified Data.ConfigFile as DC
import qualified Control.Monad.Except as CME


-- | The foundation object
data JRState = JRState {
        secureOnly :: Bool  -- ^ restrict connections to HTTPS
    }


main :: IO ()
main = (CME.runExceptT $ pipe (JRState False)) >>= estate


estate :: Show t => Either t JRState -> IO ()
estate (Right state) = return ()
estate (Left err) = do
    putStrLn $ "<<" ++ show err ++ ">>"
    return ()


pipe :: (CME.MonadError DC.CPError m, CME.MonadIO m) => JRState -> m JRState
pipe site = do
    cp <- CME.join $ CME.liftIO $ return $ DC.readstring DC.emptyCP{DC.optionxform=id} "secureSession = True\n"
    DC.get cp "DEFAULT" "secureSession" >>= return . nubb where
        nubb (Left err) = error err
        nubb (Right value) = site{secureOnly = value}
```

when run, produces

> <<(ParseError "couldn't parse value True from (DEFAULT/secureSession)","genericget")>>

which has obviously come from the putStrLn in estate.  But I would expect that the extraction of the value, in pipe and nubb (silly names, I know) would force a Boolean context and thus force the conversion of the True string to a Bool.  I've tried 1 and Yes with the same result.  What's going on?

Comment: Step 1: whittle down your code to the smallest chunk you can that still produces this error. I bet you can produce this message in just one line of code of no more than, say, 20 lexemes, if you try. This will significantly reduce the work that an expert in the ConfigFile library will have to do to help you, increasing the probability that you get help.

Comment: OK, original question reworked with minimal self-contained sample.  Still a bit more than 20 lexemes though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a more minimal program with similarly problematic behavior:

```
import qualified Data.ConfigFile as DC
import qualified Control.Monad.Except as CME

main = CME.runExceptT pipe >>= print
pipe = do
    cp <- DC.readstring DC.emptyCP{DC.optionxform=id} "secureSession = True\n"
    DC.get cp "DEFAULT" "secureSession" >>= nubb

nubb :: Either String Bool -> m Bool
nubb = undefined
```

When it's stripped down to this bare-bones form, it's obvious what has gone wrong: you are asking `DC.get` to return an `Either String Bool` when in fact you should simply be asking it to return a `Bool`. Simple fix for the stripped-down version is to eliminate the `>>= nubb` part of that line entirely; it should be easy to translate this fix back into your bigger context.